# Seems git turned a folder into a text file

Tags: git

I have code in a repo that I've been happily pushing up for many a month.
Today I checked and there is a local folder named 'pages' in my working dir, but in the origin, it is only a text file.

```
PS W:\dev> git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Looking at the local files

```
PS W:\dev> ls .\pages\


    Directory: W:\dev\pages


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        29/01/2022   7:09 pm                charts
d-----        21/12/2020   1:56 pm                tables
d-----        30/12/2020   3:58 pm                transactions
```

This is what the pages files looks like in the repo, just a string

[image]

I don't have anything in my gitignore file.

Could someone let me know how I can add the 'pages' directory?
Bonus points if someone can tell me what I did wrong to accomplish this weirdness.

As suggested, I checked if it was a sub-repo, but does not seem to be the case:
[image]

Comment: do you have detailed steps to **reproduce** the issue?

Comment: No clearly he doesn't, cause then he wasn't asking us how this case could have been caused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the problem in the end by deleting the pages directory in origin.

Then, denied the unlink on pull:

```
> git pull
Unlink of file 'pages' failed. Should I try again? (y/n) n
Removing pages
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
pages | 1 -
1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
delete mode 160000 pages
```

Add them again:  `git add .\pages\`

Now they appear again and seem to track fine.

Answer (score 3):

`pages` is a submodule.

Check if there is a `.gitmodules` file at the root of your repository, you will see the details about what repo this `pages` submodule comes from.

Comment: No .gitmodules unfortunately

Comment: Is there a `pages/.git/` directory, then ?

Comment: Also not unfortunately

Comment: What do you see if you go to `pages` (`cd pages`) and run `git status` ? and `git log -3` ? do you see the history of your root repository ?

Comment: `git status` says I am up to date. git log shows commit messages that are supposed to have been on the pages?!